# Comando UPDATE em um JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-update, sql-select

Boa tarde pessoal,

Estou tentando atualizar uma coluna da minha tabela, porém essa coluna armazena um `JSON Object`, só que para isso preciso fazer um `where` com um `JSON` também.

Esta aqui é como os dados estão armazenados na minha coluna RG:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Primeiro gostaria de saber o que esta de errado nesse comando SELECT:

`select * from Pessoas where JSON_VALUE(Rg, '$.uf') LIKE '%35%'`

E o meu comando UPDATE tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

`update Pessoas set Rg=JSON_MODIFY(Rg, '$.Uf', 'SP') where JSON_VALUE(Rg, '$.uf') LIKE '%35%'`

Alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer o select e esse update, por favor? E o que está errado nos meus comandos? Não consegui entender como fazer esses dois comandos quando tem um `JSON OBJECT` envolvido.